# Why and When an android application has multiple tasks?

Tags: android

Activities in an android application arranged in a task back stack.
When we use a single task launch mode for an activity then it can only belong to one task throughout all tasks in the app.
It's vague to me why an application may or should has multiple tasks?

I saw [Understand Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: @MasoudDarzi the question is `It's vague to me why an application may or should has multiple tasks?`. The article I linked to writes about `Managing Tasks` and it writes about `launchMode` which should answer the question. `A task is a cohesive unit that can move to the "background" when users begin a new task or go to the Home screen, via the Home button. While in the background, all the activities in the task are stopped, but the back stack for the task remains intact—the task has simply lost focus while another task takes place`

Comment: @Zun it's not about managing Task. it's about multi-task in one application. and what is the reason to have another task in one applicaton

Comment: In a multi-task application you have to manage tasks. The article I linked to explains what tasks are, why to use it, when to use it. read it more precisely ! @MasoudDarzi

Comment: actually we read that article but can you say a use case what is needed to have two tasks in one application? @Zun

Comment: The article does give an example, read it more precisely ! Here's how to implement it https://medium.com/@evanfang/truly-understand-tasks-and-back-stack-intent-flags-of-activity-2a137c401eca or https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: To give another example: if you open two tasks in a mail app you can write two emails en both screens will appear in the app switcher. This allows you to change between screens of 1 app.

Comment: @zun the article is not the point again I have read them beore . and also the email app can be done without two tasks!. I  think we don't have a similar understanding of task. by the way thanks to you  man

Comment: @Zun the email app use case was great. thanks to you man

Answer (score 4):

Take for example the Native Google Dialer. There the Incall Screen is opened in another task. That is how you can be in a call, but at the same time you can browse your contacts. Like almost they are different apps :) Otherwise if the Contacts Activity was in the back stack how would you do that?